# An idea to find range with $|\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}|\geq2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality

How can find range of $f(x)=\frac {4x^2+8x+1}x$ by $$|\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}|\geq2$$ 
I can find range of that function with inverse function ,but how can I apply this inequality to the function  ? thanks for you idea(s).

Answer (score 2):

First simplify  $f(x)=\frac {4x^2+8x+1}x=4x+8+\frac 1x$
so 
$$f(x)-8=4x+\frac {1}{x} \to $$multiply by $\frac 12$
$$\frac{1}{2}(f(x)-8)=2x+\frac{1}{2x}=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\\
|\frac{1}{2}(f(x)-8)|\geq 2\\|f(x)-8|\geq 4$$